# Compute Euler characteristic $\chi(S^2 \times S^3)$

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

This is a question from an undegraduate Topology course

> Compute the Euler characteristic $\chi(S^2 \times S^3)$

For topological polyhedra $\chi(X \times Y)=\chi(X) \times \chi(Y) \implies \chi(S^2 \times S^3)=\chi(S^2) \times \chi(S^3)$

Need to find $\chi(S^2)$ and $\chi(S^3)$ but I only know how to calculate the Euler characteristic for polyhedra

Comment: What is your definition of Euler characteristic?

Comment: Let $P$ be a polyhedron which is homeomorphic to a closed surface $S$. Suppose $P$ has $f$ faces, $e$ edges and $v$ vertices. Then $\chi(P)=f-e+v$

Comment: But $S^2\times S^3$ is not (homeomorphic, homotopy equivalent, etc. to) a surface. How are you defining its Euler characteristic?

Comment: I am not sure how to calculate it.. I only know the formula for polyhedra

Comment: @amiz9 First you have to make sense of a definition before calculating with the definition. Is it defined by triangulating the manifold and computing alternating sum of it's $k$ simplices? You must be reading about them from somewhere, so try to look for what the definition is.

Comment: @BalarkaSen I will have look back over my notes then

Comment: The Euler characteristic of an even dimensional sphere is $2$, while that of an odd dimensional sphere is $0$. There are many ways to see this. If you know about cell decompositions, you could just decompose $S^n$ into the union of a $0$-cell and an $n$-cell. Then $\chi(S^n)=1+(-1)^n$.